# How can I refer to a current working directory in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt

In pure C++ I can get access to a file "file.txt" setted in working directory just by "file.txt". In qt I need to certainly specify path like "d:/qt projects/project69/file.txt". Is there some way to get "d:/qt projects/project69" by some kind of standartPath? I know about applicationDirPath() and others; they return build-path but not a working directory path.

Comment: _In qt I need to certainly specify path like "d:/qt projects/project69/file.txt"._ You do?  Did you try using just the file name?  Perhaps the current working directory is not what you think it is...

Comment: I do not know whether you ask for setting the working directory for Qt Creator itself or for the application you are creating, using Qt Creator. If it is the latter, use `QDir::setCurrent(const QString &)`. You can test the value with `QDir::currentPath()`.

Comment: Based on @Atmo's comment, does this answer your question? [How to change the current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630879/how-to-change-the-current-working-directory)